# How to look up for each cell of a range to each cell of another range?

Tags: excel, vba

The problem in the code is that I'm making equal a cell to a range of cells…

I want to compare each cell of range A in a Worksheet called “Ax” to each cell of range B in a Worksheet called “Bx”.

```
Sub NvxDetail()

Dim Ax As Worksheet: Set Ax = Workbooks("MODÈLE DE PROPOSITION DE CONTRAT DE SOUS-TRAITANCE.").Worksheets("Proposition de contrat")
Dim By As Worksheet: Set By = Workbooks("Suivi contrat fact").Worksheets("Détail")

Dim last_row As Integer: last_row = Ax.Cells(Ax.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
Dim arng As Range: Set arng = Ax.Range(Ax.Cells(13, 1), Ax.Cells(last_row, 1))
Dim newcttnbr As Range: Set newcttnbr = By.Cells(ByLastRow, 1)

Ax.Range("C12").Copy
    newcttnbr.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
       Application.CutCopyMode = False
       ActiveCell.Select

For i = 4 To 104
If By.Cells(2, i).Value = arng.Value Then
   By.Cells(2, i).Value = arng.Offset(0, 5)
End If
Next

End Sub
```

Updated full code :

```
Sub NvxDetail()

Dim Ax As Worksheet: Set Ax = Workbooks("MODÈLE DE PROPOSITION DE CONTRAT DE SOUS-TRAITANCE.").Worksheets("Proposition de contrat")
Dim By As Worksheet: Set By = Workbooks("Suivi contrat fact").Worksheets("Détail")

Dim arng As Range: Set arng = Ax.Range(Ax.Cells(13, 1), Ax.Cells(last_row, 1))
Dim newcttnbr As Range: Set newcttnbr = By.Cells(ByLastRow, 1)

    Ax.Range("C12").Copy
    newcttnbr.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
       Application.CutCopyMode = False
       ActiveCell.Select


For i = 4 To 104
    For Each c In arng
        If By.Cells(2, i).Value = c.Value Then
           By.Cells(2, i).Value = c.Offset(0, 5)   'update value
           Exit For
        End If
    Next
Next


End Sub
```

Comment: First of all: it would be much easier to read and understand your code if you use "speaking" names for your variables, e.g. `lastroww` doesn't sound like a ranges name ... As an answer to your question: you have to iterate over `arng` as well, i.e. having a second loop within the `For i = ` loop.

Comment: You cannot compare a cell (`By.Cells(2, i).Value` with an array (`arng.Value`). It does not make sense... Why do you calculate `lastRow` and `last_row` if you iterate from 4 to 104? Only to set two useless ranges, in the code context?

Comment: I just edited, and delete the useless varibales...

Comment: I didn't understand what u mean when u said  having a second loop within the For i =  loop.

Comment: When you compare `By.Cells(2, i).Value = arng.Value`, you're comparing a single value `By.Cells(2, i).Value` with an array `arng.Value` (i.e. multiple values - see [this on VBA arrays](https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-array/#Reading_from_a_Range_to_the_VBA_Array)). To really make the comparison, you'd need a second loop to compare to all values in the array -- if that's what you intend.

Comment: I'm not sure that i understand everything... I need a loop for Worksheet "By" and another loop for Worksheet "Ax" . But how I can compare 2 different loop, I can't use ```For``` in another ```For```. Can you propose an answer so i could understand how i use 2 loops in 1 macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need sth like this - if you want to compare `by.cells(2,i)` against all values of `arng`. First value that is equal will jump into the update row and then exits the for-loop that compares the values

```vb
Dim c As Range
For i = 4 To 104
    For Each c In arng
        If By.Cells(2, i).value = c.value Then
           By.Cells(2, i).value = c.Offset(0, 5)   'update value
           Exit For
        End If
    Next
Next
```